# Finding Last known occurence given a lookup date in Large dataset

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-design

I have a specific design question that has been plaguing me for quite some time.
I have a large realtime GPS Location Log table containing point entries for many thousands of assets. Points come into the database hundreds of points per day per asset. I have an index IX(asset asc,EventTime asc) to speed up point queries for targeted assets. I have a LastKnownLocation table that is used to be able to relate each asset to its most resent point. This only provides me with CURRENT last known lookup. 
My question is, does anyone know of a efficient way of being able to query the Location Log table for last known location given a specific lookup date for many assets at a time?
"Q: Where were all my assets on end of day July 1st 2012"

BTW, Since every asset reports its points with its own internal monotonic eventtime stamp, there is an implied monotonic relation to the LocationLog.LocationLogID auto inc primary key of the table in relation to each asset. This is why I can use the MAX Aggregate.

```
SELECT MAX(LocationLog.LocationLogID) FROM LocationLog 
WHERE LocationLog.fk_AssetID IN 
(
    //LIST OF required assets for report
) 
AND LocationLog.EventTime <= '2012/07/01 23:59:59'
GROUP BY LocationLog.fk_AssetID
```

The problem is that the database index IX gives quick access to ALL points for an individual asset. These points are then organized ordered by eventtime in the index, so the dbengine will likely do a data scan within the eventtime in the index looking for the largest LocationLogID whose date is <= lookup date. The longer its been since the asset has reported prior to lookup date, the longer the scan to find a match.

Since my Location Log is 90+ million rows and growing a 1000 asset query like this takes 50 seconds.

Finding Last known occurrence given a lookup date must be a well known design pattern, however it eludes my searches.

PS: running MSSQL2000, but migrating to Postgres

Comment: Have you tried adding an index on `EventTime` desc, `Asset` asc?

Answer (score 1):

It may help to eliminate that **IN(...)**.

Try something like

```
--
--  index on AssetID, EventTime desc
--
select
      AssetID
    , LocationID
    , EventTime
from LocationLog as a
join (
        select AssetID_1
        union
        select AssetID_2
        union
        select AssetID_3
        -- etc, list of assets needed in report
      ) as b on b.AssetID = a.AssetID
where a.EventTime = (select max(xx.EventTime) 
                       from LocationLog as xx 
                      where xx.AssetID = a.AssetID
                        and xx.EventTime <= '2012-08-28 12:05:00')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind:

- Maintain a materialized view on your locations, storing the end-of-day location for each asset for each day; or
- Partition, partition, partition! If you only have, say, a week's data in each partition such searches will be much cheaper.

I'd probably create a `end_of_day_location` table and instead of just clearing my `last_known_location` table at the end of each day I'd `INSERT` its contents into `end_of_day_location` first.

Comment: PostgreSQL, the migration target, doesn't support materialized views, although you can mimic them to some degree with triggers.

Comment: @Catcall Yep, I know. I should've been explicit about that, though it's so much the convention to maintain mat.views with triggers in Pg that I forgot to explicitly note it. Thanks.